# Wordpress javascript loaded wp_editor not working on an html loaded content that contains the editor

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I am loading an html via ajax but the html contains a tinyMCE editor by calling wp_editor. The problem is I can't switch to different view like from Text to Visual view. I am also unable to Insert media into the editor due to the same javascript error problem. Here's the javascript error upon clicking the Visual View: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s031ewzlez9hepn/screenshot-1.png

I tried a different approach by converting the textarea into tinyMCE directly by instantiating the execCommand() after the HTML has been loaded but it doesn't look like the WP tinyMCE editor. See image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2waoywdubgme8mh/screenshot-2.png

Answer (score 0):

The toggle between text / visual view is handled via QuickTags; When I clone, or load an editor instance via ajax I usually loop across the dom and find the ID of the editor instance I've just created and do something like the following;

```
var ed_id = $(this).find('textarea').attr('id');//find your editors textarea id             
tinymce.init(tinyMCEPreInit.mceInit[ed_id]);//init tinymce
quicktags({id : ed_id});//init quicktags
```

Usually works a treat.

Comment: okay Dale. You did preloaded the scripts that wp_editor() uses? Note that I'm talking about a custom backend page not on the post/page editor page.

Comment: Yes, I preloaded the required scripts. The implementation I mentioned above was for using the editor on the front end of WP via ajax. Enqueuing the editor should enqueue tinyMCE and quicktags. Eg (pre wp3.5 editor);  wp_enqueue_script(array('jquery', 'editor'));
 wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
 wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');

Comment: I use above code and editor tabs visual and text are missing.